# Python mock library: Is there any way to get corresponding return values from magic mock calls?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

When writing Python tests with the `mock` library, I often get "what arguments a method is called with" like this,

```
from __future__ import print_function
import mock

m = mock.MagicMock(side_effect=lambda x: x * x)
m(4)
print("m called with: ", m.call_args_list)
```

(this will print `m called with:  [call(4)]`). **Question**: Is there any way to get the return value (in this case, `16`)?

*Details*: In my particular scenario, I want to use side_effect to return a sub-mock object: introspecting that object to see what is called on it is important. For example, the "real code" (non-test code) might write,

```
myobj = m(4)
myobj.foo()
```

Using `side_effect` seems like a convenient way to return new sub-mock objects, but also keep around `call_args_list`. However, it doesn't seem like `MagicMock` stores return values from the `side_effect` function ... am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

What about the *wraps* parameter?

```
class MyClass:
    def foo(self, x):
        return(x * x)
```

then you can assert a call like this:

```
my_obj = MyClass()
with patch.object(MyClass, 'foo', wraps=MyClass().foo) as mocked_foo:
    my_result = my_obj.foo(4)
    mocked_foo.assert_called_with(4)
```

and my_result will contain the actual result of invoking foo()

Answer (score 1):

This is not what mocks are intended for if you'd ask me. If you want to assert a return value you should call the function directly. If you need to jump though hoops to register what a function returns, your design is most likely flawed.

If for example you have an internal function, you should not test the inner function. If you want to test the inner function, make it publicly accessible.

So instead of this:

```
def spam(input):
    def eggs(nested):
        return nested*2
    input = eggs(nested)
    return eggs(input)
```

Do this:

```
def eggs(nested):
    return nested*2

def spam(input):
    input = eggs(nested)
    return eggs(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `side_effect`, that is what mocks do already without it, they return other mocks.

You make assertions on them by doing `mymock.return_value.assert_called_once_with(4)`

If you did though, you'd just return a mock you had a reference to elsewhere from `side_effect`.

Comment: I want the "other mock returned" to be something special. m(4) is not just another MagicMock but an object with some state (in my case, mocking out a Redis server). Thanks though!

Comment: Then configure it with `m.return_value`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return_value`.

For example,

```
import unittest

import mock

def foo(m):
    myobj = m(4)
    myobj.foo()

import unittest

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        m2 = mock.MagicMock()
        m = mock.MagicMock(return_value=m2)

        foo(m)

        m.assert_called_once_with(4)
        m2.foo.assert_called_once_with()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: This requires modification to the non-testing code, which is calling m(4).

Answer (score 0):

You have a call() object.
You want to get the args INSIDE the call object.
That is, if you're getting

```
call_args_list[0] == call(3, 5)
```

you want 3 and 5.
the call() object can be indexed - refer to elem 0 for the first thing, which is the list of actual arguments.  Then, you want the 3, which is further inside it as the 0th element.

Get this with:

```
cargs = call_args_list[0]
assert cargs[0][0] == 3

>>> mockObjThing.someFunc.call_args_list[0]
call('argOne', 'argTwo') 
>>> # DAGNABBIT I want argOne!!!
>>> cargs = mockObjThing.someFunc.call_args_list[0]
>>> cargs
call('argOne', 'argTwo') 
>>> cargs[0]
('argOne', 'argTwo')
>>> cargs[0][0]
'argOne'
```